# Editing code to only copy values and not formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that searches for the text I need copied but I realized that is carrying over formulas. I need it to simply paste the values of the cells. I am not sure how to edit the following to make that happen. Any thoughts?

```
 With Initiatives.Range("B3:B500")

    Rcount = 0

    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)


        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                Rcount = Rcount + 1

                Rng.EntireRow.Copy NewSh.Rows(Rcount)



                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With
```

Comment: `NewSh.Rows(Rcount).value = Initiatives.Rows(Rng.Row).value`

Comment: @ScottCraner That worked well thank you! If you post it as an answer I would be more than happy to accept it to close out the question. As a side note, how would I modify this to also copy formatting but not formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the copy code to:

```
Rng.EntireRow.Copy
NewSh.Cells(RCount,1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

This gives you the option of copying the whole row, and chosing what method of paste you want.

Comment: This worked very well. It did slow down the overall speed a bit though. I guess that is to be expected though.

Comment: You can try doing it on the entire range at once to make it faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coping the from a source one range to a destination range

`Rng.EntireRow.Copy NewSh.Rows(Rcount)`

Have the destination range value = the source ranges value.  Just like filling a ranges values using an array.

`NewSh.Rows(Rcount).Value = Rng.EntireRow.Value`